# Como criar o arquivo mysql.socket

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Estou usando o `phpmyadmin` pois, ele esta me retornando um erro que referencia a falta do arquivo `mysql.sock`, existe uma possibilidade de instalar esse arquivo?

Erro reportado abaixo:

> **error 2002 : arquivo nao encontrado**

Comment: O erro diz só isso mesmo? Como você sabe que é exatamente o `mysql.sock` que tá faltando?

Comment: por que olhei nas pastas /opt/lampp/var/mysql e esta faltando este arquivo

Comment: faz 2 dias que estou tentando achar o erro, mas nao tenho exito, no status do xampp o banco vem como desabilitado

Comment: Tente usar sudo sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start

Comment: ele sobe, mas o meu problema é no xampp, ele nao ativa

Answer (score 1):

Você tem o comando `mysql` na linha de comando? Se sim, basta startar o serviço, fazendo:

```
$ mysql.server start
```

Comment: rafa to tentando instalar o mysql-server mas esta dando o seguinte erro Unknown job?? na parte de configuração..

Comment: Qual seu sistema operacional?

Comment: estou usando o ubuntu

Comment: Bem, você está tentando instalar pelo apt-get? Acha que pode fazer um apt-get update?

Comment: estou via aptget -install so que na hora que ele comeca a configurar ele trava nessa mensagem

Comment: e em questao do apt-get update uso normal

Comment: Dá uma olhada nisso aqui: http://askubuntu.com/questions/296946/upstart-cant-start-mysql

Parece que a primeira resposta soluciona esse caso do Uknown Job. Ao que parece, sua instalação do Mysql não está mt legal, o que pode estar interferindo no problema original, inclusive.

Comment: me parece que o mysql voltou ao normal, mas o que pretendo é que no servidor do xampp ainda esta desabilitado

Comment: Sim, deve estar desabilitado porque ele tá tomando um erro na hora de iniciar o mysql server. Você chegou a executar de novo o "mysql.server start"?

Comment: sim sim executei normal, o problema é saber o que esta ocorrendo

Comment: Se desejar realmente remover o mysql (não esqueça de fazer o backup se tiver dados importantes). apt-get remove --purge mysql, apt-get remove --purge mysql-server, depois instale novamente. No my.cnf tem o nome do arquivo de sock que ele deve criar, tente renomear esse arquivo.